# Applying a function that returns a Monad type to a list using the map function

Tags: haskell, monads

Say I want to apply a simple function `(\x -> x+1)` to all elements in the list `[1,2,3]`.

I do `map (\x -> x+1) [1,2,3]` 
and get as expected `[2,3,4]`. The return type is `Num a => [a]`.

Now what happens if my function is returning a Monad type and is defined as  `\x -> do return x+1`?
I want to apply this function somehow to all elements in the list and get back a type `(Monad m, Num a) => m [a]`.

And the value will be the same `[2,3,4]`, just wrapped with a Monad.

I've been struggling with this for a while without much progress. Any idea how can I map this function to my list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `mapM`. You can find it using Hoogle and just typing in

```
Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

You'll find it in the first few results. The only difference in the type signature is that it's generalized to `Traversable`:

```
mapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

With it, you can do things like

```
> mapM (Just . (+) 1) [1,2,3]
> Just [2,3,4]
```

Or, a bit less trivial:

```
> mapM (\x -> if x < 5 then Just x else Nothing) [1..10]
> Nothing
```

Comment: BTW `mapM` and `traverse` are the same function. `traverse` is a more "modern" spelling (the less-general `mapM` came first)

Answer (score 2):

There is a monadic version of `map` - called [`mapM`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.1/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#v:mapM):

```
mapM (\x -> return (x+1)) [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Thanks!! And how do I do the same for Map.mapWithKey if the function it takes returns a Monad ?

Comment: @GilShafriri The monadic counterpart of `mapWithKey` is `traverseWithKey`. (Note that `traverswWithKey` is actually slightly more general than that: it can accept an `Applicative ` computation rather than a `Monad`ic one. But all monads are also applicatives, so this should do what you want.)

Comment: Thanks!! I just found mapWithKeyM. Both are working fine!